Copying symlinks as symlinks
I’m attempting to copy a symlink of a file in one directory to another directory.
I need the copy to be a symlink, not a hard link or a broken symlink.
cp -A and cp -P generated broken (flashing) symlinks as indicated by file -b <copied_symlink_file_name>.
cp and cp -R create hard links.
How would I create a copy of the symlink without resorting to ln -s and creating a new symlink from the original file (therefore requiring knowledge of its inode)?
Thanks for your help.

cp -P will work as long as the original symlink created is a absolute symlink to the source rather than a relative one.

You don't need to know the inode if you use ln -s: ln -s destination $(realpath source-file).

@OliverKnodel Right idea, but other way 'round: ln -s $(realpath source) destination

@OliverKnodel, I agree.  I misspoke. I was intending to ask about a solution if I don’t know the original path.

@GMaster, thanks. That makes sense. Is there a way to automatically determine the full real path to the source file from a relative symlink?

@TheorVHP Yes. readlink -e symlink

@GMaster, yes, readlink -f worked. Using -e instead resulted in an error.
Is that because I’m using macOS?

@TheorVHP There is a subtle difference between -f and -e. See the help readlink --help for the explanation. (Should not be a macOS thing, but I don't have access to macOS to check)
